Azure DevOps deploy static website to Azure Storage Container / ADLSg2
I am porting a simple webpack based static client side application from GitLab to Azure DevOps. Following the build stage I need to deploy the contents of the dist folder to an Azure ADLSg2 storage container that hosts the client side application.
The following partial shows the working deployment stage from the .gitlab-ci.yaml that uses the Azure CLI:
prod-deploy-azure:
  stage: deploy
  image: mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
  dependencies:
    - 'prod-build'
  before_script:
    - 'az login --service-principal -u ${AZURE_SP_ID} -p ${AZURE_SP_SECRET} --tenant ${AZURE_TENANT}'
    - 'STORAGE_KEY=`az storage account keys list --account-name ${AZURE_STORAGE_NAME_DEV} --output json --query "[0].value"`'
    - 'az storage container create --auth-mode key --account-key ${STORAGE_KEY} --account-name ${AZURE_STORAGE_NAME_DEV} --name ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER} --public-access blob'
  script: # Check that the dist directory exists from the build stage
    - |
      if [ -d 'dist' ] ; then
       cd dist
       pwd; 
       ls -latrR;
       az storage blob upload-batch --auth-mode key --account-key ${STORAGE_KEY} --account-name ${AZURE_STORAGE_NAME_DEV} --overwrite true --source ${PWD} --destination ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER}
      else
       echo 'No dist directory abort deployment to ' ${AZURE_STORAGE_NAME_DEV} ${AZURE_STORAGE_CONTAINER}
      fi;

However, despite some investigation on this site and MS knowledge sites I am unable to figure out how this might be done in ADO. Any pointers or assistace would be gratefully received.

FYI: there's a https://devops.stackexchange.com/

Thanks to @Doug Deploy Static Angular App to Azure BLOB Storage
Full CICD YAML
variables:
- name: storageContainer
  value: rtt2
- name: subscription
  value: Rate Test Tool 2 (RTT2)
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
stages:
- stage: __default
  jobs:
  - job: Job
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    steps:
    - task: UseNode@1
      inputs:
        version: '20.16.0'
        force32bit: true
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: npm install
      inputs:
        script: |
            npm install
    - task: CmdLine@2
      displayName: npm run build
      inputs:
        script: |
           npm run build
    - task: AzureFileCopy@6
      displayName: Deploy Rate Test Tool 2 (RTT2) to Storage Account
      inputs:
        SourcePath: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)\dist\*'
        azureSubscription: $(subscription)
        Destination: 'AzureBlob'
        storage: $(storageContainer)
        ContainerName: '$web'
        BlobPrefix: ''
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      displayName: Delete Old Files
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(subscription)
        scriptType: 'pscore'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: 'az storage blob delete-batch -s `$web --account-name $(storageContainer) --if-unmodified-since $(Get-Date ((Get-Date).addMinutes(-5)) -UFORMAT +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ)'

